Position Y-axis on zero-value. Amcharts
How to move the Y-axis to the zero value in amCharts?
I am trying to move the Y-axis of my amCharts graph to the zero value, but it remains static on the left side. I followed the solution provided here, but it didn’t work as expected for Y-axis.
Here’s the code I’m using:


var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set up amCharts themes
root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

// Create the chart
var container = root.container.children.push(
  am5.Container.new(root, {
    layout: root.verticalLayout,
    width: am5.percent(100),
    height: am5.percent(100),
  }),
);

// Add a title
var title = container.children.push(
  am5.Label.new(root, {
    text: "Main Chart Garph",
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    x: am5.p50,
    centerX: am5.p50,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  }),
);

var chartContainer = container.children.push(
  am5.Container.new(root, {
    layout: root.horizontalLayout,
    width: am5.percent(100),
    height: am5.percent(100),
  }),
);

// Add a left title
var leftTitle = chartContainer.children.push(
  am5.Label.new(root, {
    text: "Left Title",
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    rotation: -90,
    textAlign: "center",
    y: am5.p50,
    centerY: am5.p50,
    paddingRight: 10,
  }),
);

// Add a bottom title
var bottomTitle = container.children.push(
  am5.Label.new(root, {
    text: "Bottom title",
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    x: am5.p50,
    centerX: am5.p50,
    paddingTop: 10,
  }),
);

var chart = chartContainer.children.push(
  am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: true,
    panY: true,
    wheelY: "zoomXY",
    pinchZoomX: true,
    pinchZoomY: true,
  }),
);

// Create X and Y axes
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
      minGridDistance: 50,
      stroke: am5.color(0x000000), // Set the color of the X axis line
      strokeWidth: 2, // Set the width of the X axis line
    }),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
  }),
);

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
      minGridDistance: 50,
      stroke: am5.color(0x000000), // Set the color of the Y axis line
      strokeWidth: 2, // Set the width of the Y axis line
    }),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
  }),
);

// Create series
var series0 = chart.series.push(
  am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    calculateAggregates: true,
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueYField: "y",
    valueXField: "x",
    valueField: "value",
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      labelText: "{text}\nx: {valueX}, y: {valueY}",
    }),
  }),
);

series0.data.setAll([
  { x: -5, y: -5 },
  { x: -4, y: -4 },
  { x: -3, y: -3 },
  { x: -2, y: -2 },
  { x: -1, y: -1 },
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 1, y: 1 },
  { x: 2, y: 2 },
  { x: 3, y: 3 },
  { x: 4, y: 4 },
  { x: 5, y: 5 },
]);

//series0.set("heatRules", []);
//series0.strokes.template.set("strokeOpacity", 0);

// Remove cursor helper lines

// Set up events
xAxis.on("start", updateAxisPosition);
xAxis.on("end", updateAxisPosition);
yAxis.on("start", updateAxisPosition);
yAxis.on("end", updateAxisPosition);
chart.yAxesAndPlotContainer.events.on("positionchanged", updateAxisPosition);
chart.plotContainer.events.on("boundschanged", updateAxisPosition);

function updateAxisPosition() {
  var plotWidth = chart.plotContainer.width();
  var plotHeight = chart.plotContainer.height();

  // Update X axis position
  var x =
    xAxis.get("renderer").positionToCoordinate(xAxis.valueToPosition(0)) -
    plotWidth;
  if (x > 0) {
    x = 0;
  }
  if (x < -plotWidth) {
    x = -plotWidth;
  }
  yAxis.set("x", x);

  // Update Y axis position
  var y =
    yAxis.get("renderer").positionToCoordinate(yAxis.valueToPosition(0)) -
    plotHeight;
  if (y > 0) {
    y = 0;
  }
  if (y < -plotHeight) {
    y = -plotHeight;
  }
  xAxis.set("y", y);
}
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>



I expected the Y-axis to move to the zero value, but it remains on the left side of the chart. Could you please help me identify what I might be doing wrong or suggest another approach to achieve this?

Your question refers to what exactly? amCharts, amCharts4, or amCharts5? Your code is for amCharts5. Just because you put more tags on it, you won't get an answer.
